# JSP/JSTL : Initialize Multiple variables in one statement

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am pretty new to JSTL. I am working on optimizing an existing code base. Is there a way in JSTL to initialize multiple variable in one statement.

I have a code segment like this:

```
<c:set var="dttoplayer" value="" />
<c:set var="tablettoplayer" value="" />
<c:set var="mobiletoplayer" value="" />
```

I want to do something like this:

```
int a,b,c=0;
```

Is it possible to do that in JSP/JSTL?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Even if that was possible (it's not), this wouldn't optimize anything at all. Don't try to optimize things that don't need to, and would make the code less readable. Measure where the performance problems are, and optimize those parts. Usually, the performance problems are in too complex algorithms (O(n^2) instead of O(n), for example), and in IO (too many, or bad SQL queries, for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cant do that . `c:set` is jstl tag interpreted as tags when executed , not like your java statements

> Name of the exported scoped variable to hold the value specified in
>   the action. The type of the scoped variable is whatever type the value
>   expression evaluates to.

says [`c:set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) docs.